# Are there any ways of hiding object in Figma?

Tags: website-design, interface-design, wireframing, figma

I am facing problem when I need to change the icons, are there any options in figma to hide the icons or object?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you want to hide something in order to change it, since you can use components to instantly change your icons. However, you can hide any object by clicking on the eye icon in the layers panel (you need to hover over it first), or use the shortcut keys <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> on Windows or <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> on Mac.

[image]